# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: 1062, Duplicate entry for key when running Django migration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I have a problem with my django migrations. Before making the changes my table contained the following columns:

```
STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Incomplete', 'Incomplete')
    )

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,  max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=COUNTRY, null=True, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default='Pending')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    balance = models.DecimalField(default='0.00', max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, null=True, editable=True)
```

but when I added the new fields:

```
api_key = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
key_exp = models.DateTimeField(default=one_day_hence, editable=False)
```

I keep getting

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry
>   'fc1d481d-add2-4d9c-92d9-a1b05018730a' for key 'api_key'")

when running migrations.

First of all, I find it suspicious since django will provide a different value for any `default=uuid.uuid4`. I tried migrating several times but I get the same error but with a different key.
Secondly, I tried to remove `unique=True` but this didn't change anything, the error is the same.

Any idea why and how I can solve this?

EDIT:

I found why this might be happening...I already have some records in my table and when migrating, django adds the new column `api_key` with the same default value for all the existing records. (i found this after deleting the `unique` field and deleting the the latest migrations)

It will indeed add a different value for new records, but how can i make it add a different value for the existing records in the table?

Comment: Why didn't you use `UUIDField`? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: As well as the duplicate question, the docs have a section for [migrations that add unique fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields)

Comment: You do not need id. every model have id field by default